# Open VPN | Network mananger

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am writing you today because i have a problem setting up an open vpn connection. I have my own OpenVPN server that works fine. With my file client.conf and client.ovpn i am able to connect to my vpn server without any problem on android, windows and manjaro but on Ubuntu when i've tried to import my connection, I've got the message:

[image: French Network Manager Open]

Here is my client file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 19X.XXX.XXX.XXX
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key # A ne pas diffuser
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1 # A ne pas diffuser
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

If you have any idea of what is the problem please tell me.

Thank you,

Comment: Sorry, i just realized that the like i've posted do not work.       http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=647075networkmanager.png

Comment: have you installed openvpn plugin for network manager?

Answer (score 0):

The import function always sucked rather hard on Ubuntu. I know that's annoying, but when I did manage to import the configuration files, the imported file usually didn't manage to get the location of the crt and key files right.  So, you can bet you  have to do that manually any way unless you put them on specific places and refer to them by full path.

Anyway, I tested your file and it indeed does not work.  There is, however, one thing that immediately jumps to the eye: you added comments after certain configuration lines.  That is not supported everywhere.  I removed both the `# A ne pas diffuser` and, there you go: Imports just fine.

Comment: Since the answer worked for you, please accept it as an answer (click he tick)